# Recursivity in SQL Server not updating rows inside recursive procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, sql-server-2012-express

I'm developing a database on SQL Server 2012 Express Edition SP1.

I want to do a recursion with these two stored procedures:

```
Create procedure [dbo].[DisaggreagateChildren]
      @parentCode nvarchar(20) 
    , @parentLevel tinyint  
    , @parentFlag tinyint   
    , @childrenFlag tinyint 
as
begin
    declare @aggregationId int
          , @childCode nvarchar(20)
          , @childLevel tinyint;

    declare @tempChilds table (
        Code nvarchar(20),
        CodeLevel tinyint)

    [ ... ]

    set rowcount 1
    select @childCode = code, @childLevel = CodeLevel from @tempChilds

    -- Loop all child codes.
    while @@rowcount <> 0
    begin
        -- Get first code and delete it from temporary table.
        set rowcount 0
        select * from @tempChilds where code = @childCode and CodeLevel = @childLevel;
        delete @tempChilds where code = @childCode and CodeLevel = @childLevel;

        if (@childLevel = 1)
            update dbo.CODES
                set COMMISIONING_FLAG = @childrenFlag
                where ID_CODE = @childCode and CODE_LEVEL = @childLevel;
        else
        begin
            update dbo.CODES
                set COMMISIONING_FLAG = @parentFlag
                where ID_CODE = @childCode and CODE_LEVEL = @childLevel;

            -- Recursive call to disaggregate @childCode's childrens.
            EXEC dbo.DisaggreagateChildren @childCode, @childLevel, @parentFlag, @childrenFlag
        end

        -- Get next code.
        set rowcount 1
        select @childCode = code, @childLevel = CodeLevel from @tempChilds
    end -- while end
    set rowcount 0

end -- Procedure end.
go

Create procedure [dbo].[Disaggreagate]
      @parentCode nvarchar(20)          -- Code to disaggregate.
    , @parentLevel tinyint              -- Code's level.
    , @withChildren bit                 -- Disaggragate with childrens?
    , @isManual bit                     -- Is manual or automatic disaggregation?
as
begin
    Declare @parentFlag tinyint
          , @childrenFlag tinyint
          , @trancount int;

    [ ... ]

    -- Star transaction.
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    if @trancount = 0
        begin transaction
    else
        save transaction Disaggreagate;

    begin try
        -- Update parent code commissioning flag.
        Update dbo.CODES
            set COMMISIONING_FLAG = @parentFlag
            where CODE = @parentCode and CODE_LEVEL = @parentLevel;

        -- If it is a disaggregation with children, disaggregate its children.
        if (@withChildren = 1)
        begin
            EXEC dbo.DisaggreagateChildren @parentCode, @parentLevel, @parentFlag, @childrenFlag
        end

        if @trancount = 0
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int
            , @message nvarchar(2048)
            , @xactState smallint;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER()
            , @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            , @xactState = XACT_STATE();
        if @xactState = -1
            rollback;
        if @xactState = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xactState = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction Disaggreagate;

        raiserror(N'Error: %i, %s', 16, 1, @error, @message);
    end catch
end -- Procedure end.
go
```

The update inside `Disaggreagate` works perfectly, but the updates in `DissaggreagateWithChildren` doesn't work. I don't see the changes after execution.

What's happening?

Sample data:

```
CodeLevel | 3 | 2 | 1 |
----------+---+---+---+
Code      | 0 |   |   |
----------+---+---+---+
Code      |   | 1 |   |
----------+---+---+---+
Code      |   |   | 2 |
----------+---+---+---+
Code      |   |   | 3 |
----------+---+---+---+
Code      |   | 4 |   |
----------+---+---+---+
Code      |   |   | 5 |
----------+---+---+---+
Code      |   |   | 6 |
----------+---+---+---+
```

On `Aggregations` table I have codes 0, 1 and 4.
On `Aggregations_Childs` table I have codes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: It's rare to need to use loops and/or recursive procedure calls - you should generally strive to write a single query that identifies all rows to be updated and their new values as a single `UPDATE` query. Unfortunately, there's so much mechanism here that I find it hard to see what actual logic is being applied. Could you maybe create a small set of sample data, the parameters that you'd use in calling the above code, and what the expected outcome is on the sample data?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have asked because I think I will need to add a commit inside the recursive procedure.

Comment: I think it's simply an issue with the use of `@@rowcount` and `set rowcount`

Comment: in the end, are you simply trying to add branches, or prune branches from a self joined tree? i.e. I had code 0 whose children are 1 and 4 and whose grandchildren are 2,3 (children of 1) and 5,6 (children of 4).  so if I remove child 4 I also need to remove 5,6 since they are connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, as I don't fully understand what your stored procedures are doing, but I believe your usage or `rowcount` and `@@rowcount` are causing the issue of nothing updating.

If you run the following in SQL Management Studio:

```
set rowcount 1
print @@rowcount
```

You will notice `0` is returned. Are you expecting that this would return `1`?

If you then run the below to set the variable `@tempId`:

```
declare @temp table (id int)
insert into @temp (id) values (1)

declare @tempId int    
select top 1 @tempId = id from @temp

select @@rowcount
```

The row count becomes 1, because of this statement: `select top 1 @tempId = id from @temp`

So the logic that controls your loop, will always be false:

```
while @@rowcount <> 0
```

Here's the simplified test I carried out to replicate your logic where it never gets into the while loop, hopefully it matches what you are trying:

```
declare @temp table (id int)

insert into @temp (id) values (1)
insert into @temp (id) values (2)
insert into @temp (id) values (3)
insert into @temp (id) values (4)

declare @tempId int

set rowcount 1
select top 1 @tempId = id from @temp
print 'step 1 row count: ' + cast(@@rowcount as varchar(10))

-- Loop
while @@rowcount <> 0
begin
    -- delete first id
    set rowcount 0        
    print 'step 2 row count: ' + cast(@@rowcount as varchar(10))
    delete @temp where id = @tempId
    print 'step 3 row count: ' + cast(@@rowcount as varchar(10))
    -- Get next id
    set rowcount 1
    print 'step 4 row count: ' + cast(@@rowcount as varchar(10)) 
    select top 1 @tempId = id from @temp
    print 'step 4 row count: ' + cast(@@rowcount as varchar(10)) 
end -- while end
set rowcount 0

-- check what's left
select * from @temp
```

You could rework it to use `EXISTS` logic on the `WHILE` loop instead, something like:

```
declare @temp table (id int)

insert into @temp (id) values (1)
insert into @temp (id) values (2)
insert into @temp (id) values (3)
insert into @temp (id) values (4)

declare @tempId int = 1
select * from @temp

-- Loop to recursively delete
while exists (select top 1 id from @temp where id = @tempId)
begin
    -- Get next code        
    select top 1 @tempId = id from @temp    
    -- delete select id    
    delete @temp where id = @tempId   
    -- how many rows left
    select count(id) as RowsLeft from @temp
    select @tempId = @tempId + 1     
end -- while end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit your savepoint, I think.

```
if @trancount = 0
            commit
ELSE
BEGIN
    commit Disaggreagate
END
```

Since you only commit if there's not an incoming transaction, but you create a savepoint, I don't believe it's getting committed.

Comment: Thanks but I debugging I see that savepoint is not used. I don't think this is the problem. Maybe I need to add another commit.

Comment: You only need to commit, if the sp was the one that created the transaction. Please check this [(example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx)